# List all kubernetes nodes within a specific nodepool. How can this be done?

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for a way to list all nodes in a specific nodepool but not able to find any examples.

Is there a way to specify meta data with json? Or use an awk filter?

The following will list all nodes in the cluster
`kubectl get nodes`

Comment: I have no cluster with nodepools to test but probally this is achivable with https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/ You can use them to filter the resources returned. So maybe somehting like kubectl get nodes --field-selector pathToLabel=nodepool-name

Comment: Aren't nodepools identified by labels on the Node objects? Assuming that's the case you should be able to use a label selector (`kubectl get nodes -l ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes have label with their node group.
To print a list of all of yours nodes and their node group run:

```
> kubectl get node -o=custom-columns='node_name:metadata.name, node_group:metadata.labels.cloud\.google\.com/gke-nodepool'
node_name                                    node_group
gke-ml-prd-default-node-pool-03d09fca-jj3x   default-node-pool
gke-ml-prd-default-node-pool-4649f5b7-j1qc   default-node-pool
gke-ml-prd-default-node-pool-4a9ff740-2my4   default-node-pool
gke-ml-prd-default-node-pool-9a199b2d-q573   default-node-pool
```

Of course you need to change the label according to your cloud provider.
Take a look on the labels of one of your nodes with `kubectl describe <node_name>` and find the relevant label name.

These are names in the popular cloud providers.

- **gke**: cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool
- **eks**: eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup
- **aks**: kubernetes.azure.com/agentpool

You can also filter for specific group with
`kubectl get node --selector='cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=default-node-pood'`